# How to create a random time within a range

Tags: ruby

How can I create a random time within a time interval? I want to create a random time between 9am and 11:30am.

Answer (score 9):

use `rand()`

`rand(Time.parse('9 am')..Time.parse('11:30 am'))`

Comment: `require 'time'` required.

Comment: A bit curious why this works. I tried with some custom class other than `Time`, like `rand(Int.new(1)..Int.new(3))` where `Int` is a class with `succ` and `<=>` methods, but it always ends up with `'rand': no implicit conversion of Range into Integer`.

Comment: @ArieXiao since ranges can have a large (or even infinite) number of elements, `rand` _calculates_ the new value using only the beginning and end of the range. It first determines the difference via `Time.parse('11:30 am') - Time.parse('9 am')` which is `9000.0`. It then calculates a random offset between 0 and that difference, e.g. `rand * 9000.0` which could return `1234.5`. Finally that offset is added back to the beginning of the range, i.e. `Time.parse('9 am') + 1234.5` which gives the final value. In short: your custom class must also respond to `+` and `-` the way `Time` does.