# rand(Range) - no implicit conversion of Range into Integer

Tags: ruby

A follow up on the question [How to create a random time between a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292568/how-to-create-a-random-time-between-a-range)
.

`Kernel#rand` works with `Time` range:

```
require 'time'
rand(Time.parse('9 am')..Time.parse('11:30 am'))
```

But when I tried with a custom class, I ended up with the error:

> `rand': no implicit conversion of Range into Integer (TypeError)

```
class Int
  include Comparable

  attr_reader :num

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def succ
    Int.new(num + 1)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    num <=> other.num
  end

  def to_s
    "Int(#{num})"
  end

  def to_int
    @num
  end

  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end

puts rand(Int.new(1)..Int.new(3))
```

Why? What am I missing in the custom class? Can we use such a custom class in `rand(Range)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any documentation for what specifically `Kernel#rand` expects from a `Range` argument but we can get a look at what's going on by overriding `respond_to?` in your class and then watching as things fall apart:

```
def respond_to?(m)
  puts "They want us to support #{m}"
  super
end
```

Doing that tells us that `rand` wants to call the `#-` and `#+` methods on your `Int` instances. This does make some sense given that `rand(a..b)` is designed for working with integers.

So we throw in quick'n'dirty implementations of addition and subtraction:

```
def -(other)
  self.class.new(to_int - other.to_int)
end

def +(other)
  self.class.new(to_int + other.to_int)
end
```

and we start getting rand `Int`s out of our calls to `rand`.

---

I'm not sure where (or if) this is documented so you'll have to excuse a bit of hand waving. I normally spend some time rooting around the Ruby source code to answer this sort of question but I lack the time right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More specifically, `rand` is expecting the following 2 methods on `Int`: `-` that accepts `Int` and returns `Integer`, and `+` that accepts `Integer` and returns `Int`.

Comment: Generally, `a + b` should yield something with the same class as `a` and similarly for `a - b` (not always but it is a good rule of thumb). I added the `to_int` calls as that's the easiest way to open up an `Int` and it also makes sense for `Int` to be able to participate in arithmetic with other integer-isn things.

Comment: yes, that makes the interface more general and not specifically for the `rand`.

Comment: In order to work with `rand`, `-` must return the difference as a number (just like `Time#-` returns a float when given another `Time`). A working implementation in that sense would be `def -(other); num - other.num; end` and `def +(offset); Int.new(num + offset); end`

Comment: @Stefan But it actually does work when `+` and `-` return `Int`s. I suspect the result is functionally equivalent to `r.to_a.sample` but there's no specification and I haven't examined the MRI source so, again, hand waving.

Comment: @muistooshort you're right, it does work. But just because `Int` implements `to_int`, which allows `rand` to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @Stefan Right. I'm not disagreeing with you I'm just qualifying my statement because specifications in Ruby generally boil to "what RMI does". Anyway, looks like the OP went through the source in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294686/479863) which is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit more to @mu-is-too-short's answer, I checked the source of `Random#rand` and the following is the current implementation logic for `rand(Range)`:

1. Get the begin, end, and `vmax` from the `Range` object ([call `range_values`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0c2f92daad93c57af1720e3cbafcdcae9bd0cd62/random.c#L1230)), where `vmax` is computed as ([call `id_minus`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0c2f92daad93c57af1720e3cbafcdcae9bd0cd62/random.c#L1145)):

   ```
   vmax = end - begin
   ```

   `vmax` will be used as the upper bound of the random number generation later.

   **This requires the custom class to have `-` method defined.**
2. Generate a random number based on the type of `vmax`:

   - If it is not `Float` and can be coerced to `Integer` ([`rb_check_to_int`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0c2f92daad93c57af1720e3cbafcdcae9bd0cd62/random.c#L1232)), generate a random `Integer` less than `vmax`.

     **In this case, the `-` method should either return an `Integer`, or an object which responds to `to_int` method.**
   - If it is `Numeric` and can be converted to `Float` with `to_f`, ([`rb_check_to_float`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0c2f92daad93c57af1720e3cbafcdcae9bd0cd62/random.c#L1252)), generate a random `Float` number less than `vmax`.

     **In this case, the `-` method should return a `Numeric` number which can be converted to `Float` with method `to_f`.**
3. Add the random number to `begin` to yield the result ([call `id_add`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0c2f92daad93c57af1720e3cbafcdcae9bd0cd62/random.c#L1294)).

   **This requires the custom class to have `+` method defined, which accepts the result of the random number generated in step 2 (either `Integer`, or `Float`) and returns the final result for `rand`.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is because you are trying to use rand() on objects of your custom class.

```
`rand': no implicit conversion of Range into Integer (TypeError)
```

This error message clearly mentions that ruby was unable to convert your range into integer. Based on your code snippet, following works and might be what you are looking for.

```
puts rand(Int.new(1).to_int..Int.new(3).to_int)
```